# How much whitespace should exist between code elements?

Tags: coding-style, whitespace, code-formatting

I cannot seem to find a style guide for how much whitespace should exist between each "code element".

Are there cases where:

```
function myFunction() {
var noNewLine;
}
```

Is better than:

```
function myFunction() {

var oneLine;

}
```

Or are there cases where it is wise to declare various variables on the same line:

```
function myFunction() {

var x; var x; var z;

}
```

Would it be always wrong, even if some context or connection exists between all those variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of what you want to communicate. However, as I work on larger projects with more people, I'm discovering that it is very important to be consistent.  Stylistic choices tax the mind unnecessarily, and consistency trains the brain how to scan what it is looking for quickly.  Most languages have a recommended style guide, so if you are starting a new project, it might be a good idea to look through it.  If you are working on somebody else's code, just try to be consistent with their style. **Code should look like the code around it.**

My personal style with blank lines is to try to bundle related lines together.  So I will put blank lines on either side of a three or four lines which are working together to "do one thing".  E.g.

```
// Find the last good index of arr.
var finalIndex = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (isGood(arr[i])) {
        finalIndex = i;
    }
}
```

I would put blank lines around this, because they might be part of a larger calculation I'm doing, but I can describe what it is these lines do in a simple sentence.

I wouldn't recommend multiple declarations on the same line.  The reason is that, if I'm reading some code, and I see

```
x += metric(rightIndex);
```

and I don't know what `rightIndex` is, I'm going to scan upward to see where it is declared.  If you declared them like

```
var leftIndex; var middleIndex; var rightIndex;
```

I might miss it, since when I'm scanning I just see

```
var leftIndex .................................
```

whereas if it's in a block like

```
 var leftIndex;
 var middleIndex;
 var rightIndex;
```

I can see it more easily.

So there are a few rules of thumb for you.  Programmers can get kind of passionate about these topics, so just gently incorporate what is useful, discard what is useless, to create your own way.  *Jeet Kune Do*